# Transaction Submit Error MissingScriptWitnessesUTXOW

Tags: plutus

I am currently working on a very simple auction dapp and am receiving this error:

```
{
    "code": 2,
    "info": "Wallet could not send the tx.",
    "message": "\"transaction submit error ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (NonOutputSupplimentaryDatums (fromList [SafeHash \\\"c52c505c0d6e374baf48b1e78cd8bdb921d76127e6961bc9100c9e8b45192952\\\"]) (fromList [SafeHash \\\"04c56e48044dae5359a5b2d5a2a73b374f20bd6cc70206e88f42b2a91ecaa408\\\"])),UtxowFailure (ExtraRedeemers [RdmrPtr Spend 1]),UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (MissingScriptWitnessesUTXOW (fromList [ScriptHash \\\"c1c0f2fbbc40ec587e6a3fd05a43f02e3e23f9debb30d4a62e49e7bb\\\"]))),UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (UtxosFailure (CollectErrors [NoWitness (ScriptHash \\\"c1c0f2fbbc40ec587e6a3fd05a43f02e3e23f9debb30d4a62e49e7bb\\\")]))))])\""
}
```

MissingScriptWitnessesUTXOW and ExtraRedeemers are confusing me and am curious if anyone else is having these problems? I am using the cardano-serialization-lib to build and sign the transaction.

Let me know if there is any supplemental information I can provide thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this error went away after removing the first 6 characters of the script's cbor hex. For some reason the cardano-serialization library currently requires the removal of those first 6 characters.

Comment: May be it is related to this https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/issues/281and this https://forum.cardano.org/t/martify-marketplace-using-cardano-serialization-lib/89037 , handling reedemers and datums its giving problems for me too, I am building a market place using Martify Code.